# Send ctrl-a in tmux

Tags: tmux

I'm using tmux as a replacement for GNU screen, and I'm using `set-option -g prefix C-a` to use <kbd>C-a</kbd> as my default. This naturally conflicts with <kbd>C-a</kbd> as the emacs-style move to beginning of line shortcut.

In screen, <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> sends a <kbd>C-a</kbd> event to the shell, but I can't figure out how to duplicate this functionality in tmux.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For your `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key a  send-prefix
```

Comment: you save my day!